# Enable Hyper-V for the emulator for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8-emulator

I just installed visual studio 2013 and windows phone sdk 8.0 in windows 8.1 Pro. I am facing problem related to emulator to test my apps on virtual mobile.

Regarding to Hyper - V, I followed this link to check my laptop compatibility for Hyper - V.

My laptop supports Hyper - V and also its turned on from BIOS. It also have data execution prevention but it does not have SLAT.

Due to SLAT I am not able to run emulator. can anybody suggest me any other way that i can use emulator. Is any other way exists or not in the absence of SLAT..?

Answer (score 4):

"Must have a SLAT processor".

"The new emulator is built on the latest version of Microsoft Hyper-V, which requires a 64-bit CPU that includes Second Level Address Translation (SLAT), a memory virtualization technology included in most modern CPUs from Intel and AMD. SLAT (Second Level Address Translation) is required only to run the Windows Phone emulator. You can still build Windows Phone 8 apps on a non-SLAT computer; you will simply need to deploy and test them on a physical device." - [Windows Phone 8 Development Internals]

Its a MUST have kind of requirement and WP8 emulator WON'T run in absence of SLAT.